# How to load a JPEG into a bitmap image array?

Tags: objective-c, macos, bitmap, jpeg

I tried using [How to load JPG file into NSBitmapImageRep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954786/how-to-load-jpg-file-into-nsbitmapimagerep) to answer my question but I get:

"incompatible pointer types initializing 'nsbitmapimagerep *' with an expression of type 'nsimagerep *'". with respect to:

```
NSImage *controlImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [[controlImage representations] objectAtIndex:0]; //"incompatible pointer types initializing 'nsbitmapimagerep *' with an expression of type 'nsimagerep *'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is right. The representions of an `NSImage` are an `NSArray` of `NSImageRep` (see the docs):

```
@property(readonly, copy) NSArray <NSImageRep *> *representations
```

The compiler message is only a warning, so
you could cast the second line and use the direct way (without using an `NSImage`) to get an NSBitmapImageRep:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep =
     (NSBitmapImageRep *)[NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Another way avoiding the (a bit ugly casting) is:

```
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:imgData];
```

Warning: this version does NOT evaluate an @2 etc. in the filePath!

Answer (score 0):

NSBitmapImageRep is a subclass of NSImageRep, which is "semiabstract".  NSImage can store other kinds of representations, too -- like NSEPSImageRep, for EPS images.

If you're sure it's a bitmap, you should be able to simply cast it.